# What's the most elegant way of commenting / uncommenting blocks of ruby code in Vim?

Tags: vim

In VIM, at the moment when I need to comment out a section of Ruby code:

- I navigate to the first column in the row I want to comment out
- I press CTRL-v to enter visual block mode
- I navigate down till the place I want to end the operation
- I type `r<space>` if I want to uncomment the code or `r#` if I want to comment it out.

This workflow seems ok to me, are there any ways of improving this process? Are there any other tricks for commenting or uncommenting ruby code sections in vim?

Answer (score 41):

I do almost the same thing as you.

commenting:

- visual block select with `CTRL-V` then `I#` (insert `#` in the begining)

uncommenting:

- visual block select with `CTRL-V` then `X` (delete the first symbol on the line)

Please note uppercase `I` and `X`.

Comment: Yes, I didn't notice the *uppercase*, which leads me to your answer. :-) +1

Comment: any ideas of why this might not work in some cases?  I try and it only insert on the first line I blocked.  I have +visualextra installed.

Comment: I realize this is very old, but @will I found that the insert did not apply until I left visual block mode by hiting <esc> (in other words `CTRL-V` + down arrow to select first column + `I#` + `<esc>` )

Answer (score 14):

For each language (ftplugin), I write mappings which will add or remove the comment leader and move the cursor down one line. For example, in my python ftplugin, I have this:

```
noremap   <buffer> K      :s,^\(\s*\)[^# \t]\@=,\1#,e<CR>:nohls<CR>zvj
noremap   <buffer> <C-K>  :s,^\(\s*\)#\s\@!,\1,e<CR>:nohls<CR>zvj
```

I find this to be an extremely flexible setup:

- Hit `K` to comment the current line.
- Hit `K` repeatedly to comment lots of lines.
- `6K` to comment 6 lines.
- `K` in visual mode comments the whole selection.
- Everything can be uncommented in the same way using `CTRL-K`
- If lines are already commented, they won't have an additional `#` added to the start.
- If a `#` is followed by a space, it is considered a text comment and doesn't get touched.

I adapt this slightly for each language. It doesn't work as well for Old C comments (/*...*/) but I prefer not to use those anyway.

Comment: Can you explain what does `\@=` and `\@!` in you search strings mean?

Comment: I have tweaked the script slighthly to enter the C, PHP like single line commenting with the same *Shift+K* combination as given above.

`noremap   <buffer> K  :s,^\(\s*\)[^\/\/ \t]\@=,\1\/\/,e<CR>:nohls<CR>zvj`

Answer (score 6):

Some people seem to like [Nerd Commenter](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1218)

Answer (score 6):

#### I use these plugins:

1. [vim-commentary](https://github.com/tpope/vim-commentary) by Tim Pope, which defines a comment operator `gc`
2. [vim-textobj-rubyblock](https://github.com/nelstrom/vim-textobj-rubyblock), which defines `ir` (inside Ruby block) and `ar` (around Ruby block) for Ruby do ... blocks.
3. [vim-ruby](https://github.com/vim-ruby/vim-ruby) which defines `im`/`am` for inside/around Ruby method, and `iM`/`aM` for inside/around Ruby class.

#### Using this combination, I can easily comment/uncomment Ruby-specific code in Normal mode, e.g.:

1. `gcir` / `gcar` comment inside/around Ruby do/end block.
2. `gcim` / `gcam` comment inside/around Ruby method.
3. `gciM` / `gcaM` comment inside/around Ruby class.
4. Plus normal Commentary maps like `gcc` to comment a line, or `5gcc` to comment 5 lines.

All in all it's very Vim-like and natural.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried out [EnhCommentify.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=23) or [tComment.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1173)?

Comment: +1, these scripts works with almost all filetypes, just hit <m-x> and it will toggle the comments on the (selected) lines.

Comment: @SamSaffron I used to use EnhCommentify, but I find tComment to be better, IMHO.

Answer (score 5):

I like using the following:

- put cursor on the first line you want to comment out
- enter ma (no colon) to put a marker on that line
- go to the last line of the block you want to comment out
- enter :'a,.s/^/#/ and then enter

That says, from the line containing marker "a", up to the current line, substitute a hash for the beginning of the line.

Comment: It's good to know how to do it that way with markers for creating macros but for manually selecting a region like that visual mode seems so much easier to me.

Comment: I agree, this is one of the better answers here. But I personally would have this mapped to a keystroke or something helpful let alone the limitation is that '#' is not used for all scripts to comment.

Comment: i agree @dreeves and i am trying get away from a line centric approach to a block centric approach. but it's difficult after using vi for over thirty years! (-:

Answer (score 4):

After visually selecting, in block mode, the text you want to comment out, hit **I** (that is a capital i), type **#** and finally hit the escape key. It's basically the same procedure you are using currently, but using insert instead of replace.

Comment: Wow, that's nice!  But why does that only work with visual block mode, not normal visual mode?

Comment: If you take a look at vim's visual operators (http://www.vim.org/htmldoc/visual.html#visual-operators) you will see that there is no visual-characterwise insert operator nor a visual-linewise insert operator, but only a visual-block insert operator.

Comment: This is the correct answers for me - the final ```Esc``` was necessary.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this:

- Move to the first line to comment out
- press 'ESC' then
- Hit `Ctrl + q` to enter Visual Block mode
- Move done to the last line to comment out
- Hit `I`, comment out by pressing `#`
- Hit `ESC`

And to uncomment:

- Move to the first `#` of comment
- Hit `Ctrl + q` to enter Visual Block mode
- Move done to the last line to comment out
- Hit `d` to remove the comment characters

Answer (score 1):

Try [T-comment](http://git://github.com/tsaleh/vim-tcomment.git) with [Ruby block](https://github.com/nelstrom/vim-textobj-rubyblock).

I have T-comment mapped to //.

```
" Easy commenting
nnoremap // :TComment<CR>
vnoremap // :TComment<CR>
```

This allows, from anywhere in a Ruby block, to comment it out with:

```
var  (visual around Ruby)
//   (toggle comments)
```

Note that Ruby blocks has a couple of plugin dependencies that need installing, see my [Vimfiles](https://github.com/krisleech/vimfiles) for an example.

Answer (score 1):

I will recommend you an alternative way to comment using by Macro

The first, just put this in to your `.vimrc`

```
let @c="I#\ej"
let @u="^xj"
```

For the example

To comment 12 lines:

1. Navigate to the first row that you want to start your comment.
2. Type `12@c` on command mode to comment 12 lines

To uncomment 12 lines:

1. Navigate to the first row that you want to uncomment.
2. Type `12@u` on command mode to uncomment 12 lines

**The conclusion**

Commenting:

```
[quantifier]@c
```

Uncommenting:

```
[quantifier]@u
```

note: These commands will start commenting/uncommenting from your current line.

Additional:

To improve you nevigation `number.vim` can help you a lot about quantifier number.

https://github.com/myusuf3/numbers.vim

Comment: Awesome tip and I think that it should add space before exit insert mode `let @c="I# \ej"` or something like that, Thanks