# How to comment out a block of Python code in Vim

Tags: python, vim, editor

I was wondering if there was any key mapping in Vim to allow me to indent certain lines of code (whether those lines have been selected in visual mode, or *n* lines above/below current cursor position).

So basically something that converts the following

```
def my_fun(x, y):
    return x + y
```

to

```
#def my_fun(x, y):
#    return x + y
```

I am okay with using either `#` or `"""` for commenting out the relevant lines. Ideally, I would also like the same keymapping to uncomment the lines if the given lines have been commented out.

Comment: No need to reinvent the wheel, there is a [plugin: tComment](https://github.com/tomtom/tcomment_vim) for you, which supports (un)comment code for multiple languages.

Answer (score 451, accepted):

**Step 1:** Go to the the first column of the first line you want to comment.

[image: Initial State]

**Step 2:** Press: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> and select the lines you want to comment:

[image: Select lines]

**Step 3:** <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>`I`</kbd><kbd>#</kbd><kbd>space</kbd> (Enter Insert-at-left mode, type chars to insert.  The selection will disappear, but all lines within it will be modified after Step 4.)

[image: Comment]

**Step 4:** <kbd>Esc</kbd>

[image: <Esc>]

Comment: Commenting the lines this way works great. Is there some way to uncomment these lines? `Shift-I # <ESC>` didn't work (maybe I'm doing it wrong).

Comment: @rishabh-manocha: use visual block (Ctrl-V) to select all the added # and type x to delete them.

Comment: You gotta remember that Shift-I means "insert at the first non-blank in the line", so it can't be used to delete. Doing a visual selection with Ctrl-V marks the characters to modify, then "x" deletes one character in the selected area, ending up deleting the '#' characters. See ":h I" and ":h CTRL-V" in vim for more information.

Comment: Hmm... when I press Ctrl+v, I get a `;` character...? What am I doing wrong? I also tried Shift+v and then Shift+i but that does not work, I go into insert mode, and when I type // and press ESC, it only puts it on the first line.

Comment: @Samaursa Ctrl-V is probably not working on Windows. Try Ctrl-Q instead.

Comment: When I try to comment out the line all SHIFT-I does is put me into insert mode and clear the visual selection. Does this really work on Linux?

Comment: That's what is supposed to happen. Once you hit Shift-I, type some characters, and hit escape, the characters will appear in all the lines. While typing, they only show up on one line.

Comment: Doesn't work for me on OS X (Mavericks) with Vim 7.3.  I used `r` instead of Shift `i` and it worked.

Comment: To delete 2 characters (if you inserted '# '), locate the cursor at the top line you want to modify, press ctrl-v to enter visual block mode, press j (or down arrow) to highlight all lines to modify, press l (or right arrow) to highlight a 2-char width (press once per column to highlight), and then press d to delete the highlighted text.

Comment: Step 3 could use a description, especially since the `:h I` description isn't really descriptive of what happens when selecting a block-- it actually describes inserting at the line beginning, while this selection mode inserts at the left side of the selection.  So, Step 3:  `I` to switch to insert mode, where the characters entered are inserted to the left side of the selection, followed by the characters to insert on the left, followed by Step 4: Esc to finish.  Similarly, `A` appends characters after the right side of the selection block, which is useful for something like `*/` or `-->`

Comment: Also, a replacement for step3 & step4 if you prefer not to move the code to the right:  `r#` -- this is replace selected chars with '#'.  No Esc is required because unlike `I` and `A` you do not leave command mode and enter insert mode.

Comment: it doesn't work quite well when the block to be commented out contains empty lines. ideavim misses a code line per empty line found in the block :(

Comment: strangely, it did not work for me. it only add # for first line.  is "shift - I # space" means,press shift and press I # space in turn?

Answer (score 79):

one way manually

```
:set number
:10,12s/^/#
```

Comment: how do you remove them though?

Comment: @CharlieParker: `:10,12s/^#//`

Comment: Thumbs up for ex answer (old school :)

Answer (score 58):

You could add the following mapping to your .vimrc

```
vnoremap <silent> # :s/^/#/<cr>:noh<cr>
vnoremap <silent> -# :s/^#//<cr>:noh<cr>
```

Highlight your block with:

```
Shift+v
```

`#` to comment your lines from the first column.

`-#` to uncomment the same way.

Comment: Any way to make this not update the search term? With `hlsearch` on, this ends up highlight the the first character of ever line.

Comment: this one overrides # which is a valid and used command in the command mode though

Comment: @architectonic it doesn't have an effect unless you are in visual mode, and '#' is unbound in visual mode http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/visual.html#visual-operators

Comment: @ajwood Added ':noh<cr>' to the end of the replace.  noh clears highlighting until the next search so it will no longer highlight the first column on every line or affect future highlighting.

Comment: I have modified a bit : 
Ctrl + k for comment
"vnoremap <silent> <C-k> :s#^#\##<cr>:noh<cr>"
> Ctrl + u for uncomment :
"vnoremap <silent> <C-u> :s#^\###<cr>:noh<cr>"

Comment: Could someone unpack this for me, I can't understand how it works. Is it an example of the substitute command? i.e. `:s/{pattern}/{string}/[flags]` - but there are no `/` characters!

Comment: @JonathanHartley you don't have to use '/' in this case '#' is the delimiter. So :s/^/#/ and :s/^#// are the equivalent substitutions. So replace beginning of line with '#' and replace '#' at first column with ''. <cr>:noh<cr> just clears the search string so nothing is left highlighted when you are done.

Comment: @cdated Thank you! I get it now. Why would you choose delimiters which are also characters that are heavily involved in the substitution? Aren't the ones using '/' delimiters easier to read? Anyhow, best answer on the page, have all my votes.

Comment: @JonathanHartley honestly I think I just followed a pattern without thinking about it. Now I'm surprised # vs / didn't come up sooner. Changed the answer based on common sense. Thanks!

Comment: Just recovered my password so I could let you know that you are my hero.

Answer (score 36):

Highlight your block with: <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>

Comment the selected block out with: `:norm i#` (lower case i)

To uncomment, highlight your block again, and uncomment with: `:norm ^x`

The `:norm` command performs an action for every selected line. Commenting will insert a `#` at the start of every line, and uncommenting will delete that `#`.

Comment: With an up-to-date Vim and a plain config, selecting lines in visual mode (with `Shift+v`) and then using `:norm i#` only changes the first selected line. This works for me to comment lines 389 to 391: `:389,391norm i  #`

Answer (score 27):

I usually sweep out a visual block (`<C-V>`), then search and replace the first character with:

```
:'<,'>s/^/#
```

(Entering command mode with a visual block selected automatically places '<,'> on the command line) I can then uncomment the block by sweeping out the same visual block and:

```
:'<,'>s/^#//
```

Answer (score 18):

There are some good plugins to help comment/uncomment lines. For example [The NERD Commenter](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1218).

Sample shortcuts from the NERD Commenter:

```
[count]|<Leader>|cc |NERDCommenterComment|
Comment out the current line or text selected in visual mode.

[count]|<Leader>|cu |NERDCommenterUncomment|
Uncomments the selected line(s).
```

Full documentation is located [here](https://github.com/preservim/nerdcommenter/blob/master/doc/nerdcommenter.txt).

Answer (score 10):

I have the following lines in my `.vimrc`:

```
" comment line, selection with Ctrl-N,Ctrl-N
au BufEnter *.py nnoremap  <C-N><C-N>    mn:s/^\(\s*\)#*\(.*\)/\1#\2/ge<CR>:noh<CR>`n
au BufEnter *.py inoremap  <C-N><C-N>    <C-O>mn<C-O>:s/^\(\s*\)#*\(.*\)/\1#\2/ge<CR><C-O>:noh<CR><C-O>`n
au BufEnter *.py vnoremap  <C-N><C-N>    mn:s/^\(\s*\)#*\(.*\)/\1#\2/ge<CR>:noh<CR>gv`n

" uncomment line, selection with Ctrl-N,N
au BufEnter *.py nnoremap  <C-N>n     mn:s/^\(\s*\)#\([^ ]\)/\1\2/ge<CR>:s/^#$//ge<CR>:noh<CR>`n
au BufEnter *.py inoremap  <C-N>n     <C-O>mn<C-O>:s/^\(\s*\)#\([^ ]\)/\1\2/ge<CR><C-O>:s/^#$//ge<CR><C-O>:noh<CR><C-O>`n
au BufEnter *.py vnoremap  <C-N>n     mn:s/^\(\s*\)#\([^ ]\)/\1\2/ge<CR>gv:s/#\n/\r/ge<CR>:noh<CR>gv`n
```

The shortcuts preserve your cursor position and your comments as long as they start with `#` (there is space after #). For example:

```
# variable x
x = 0
```

After commenting:

```
# variable x
#x = 0
```

After uncomennting:

```
# variable x
x = 0
```

Comment: Nice, but I think you'd be better off using the simpler ```s/^/#/``` regexp.  I prefer the comment char to occur at the beginning of the line... but much more importantly, 'commenting comments' is really rather important.
I'd also drop the ```au BufEnter *.py```, since `#` comments are general enough for the commands to be used in all buffers by default.

Answer (score 10):

No plugins or mappings required.  Try the built-in "norm" command, which literally executes anything you want on every selected line.

**Add # Comments**

```
1. shift V to visually select lines
2. :norm i#
```

**Remove # Comments**

```
1. visually select region as before
2. :norm x
```

Or if your comments are indented you can do `:norm ^x`

Notice that these are just ordinary vim commands being preceded by ":norm" to execute them on each line.

More detailed answer for using "norm" command in one of the answers here

[What's a quick way to comment/uncomment lines in Vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676632/whats-a-quick-way-to-comment-uncomment-lines-in-vim/23063140#23063140)

Answer (score 6):

[NERDcommenter](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdcommenter) is an excellent plugin for commenting which automatically detects a number of filetypes and their associated comment characters. Ridiculously easy to install using [Pathogen](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen).

Comment with `<leader>cc`. Uncomment with `<leader>cu`. And toggle comments with `<leader>c<space>`.

(The default `<leader>` key in vim is `\`)

Answer (score 5):

Frankly I use a tcomment plugin for that [link](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1173). It can handle almost every syntax. It defines nice movements, using it with some text block matchers specific for python makes it a powerful tool.

Answer (score 5):

There's a lot of comment plugins for vim - a number of which are multi-language - not just python. If you use a plugin manager like [Vundle](https://github.com/gmarik/Vundle.vim/) then you can search for them (once you've installed Vundle) using e.g.:

```
:PluginSearch comment
```

And you will get a window of results. Alternatively you can just [search vim-scripts for comment plugins](https://github.com/search?q=user%3Avim-scripts%20comment).

As mentioned in other answers [NERDCommenter](https://github.com/preservim/nerdcommenter) is good one - for more info on using it see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25119977/how-to-use-nerdcomment-plugin-for-vim). Note: That the `<leader>` key is usually <kbd>\</kbd>. E.g. so to comment out a line - type: <kbd>\</kbd><kbd>cc</kbd>

Answer (score 4):

A very minimal light weight [plugin](https://github.com/tpope/vim-commentary): vim-commentary.

<kbd>**gcc**</kbd> to comment a line 
<kbd>**gcgc**</kbd> to uncomment. check out the plugin page for more.

<kbd>**v+k/j**</kbd> highlight the block then <kbd>**gcc**</kbd> to comment that block.

Answer (score 0):

**<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>K</kbd> for comment (Visual Mode):**

```
vnoremap <silent> <C-k> :s#^#\##<cr>:noh<cr>
```

**<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>U</kbd> for uncomment (Visual Mode):**

```
vnoremap <silent> <C-u> :s#^\###<cr>:noh<cr>
```