# Easily comment (C++) code in vim

Tags: c++, vim

I have looked at the following question:

[How to comment out a block of Python code in Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2561418/how-to-comment-out-a-block-of-python-code-in-vim)

But that does not seem to work for me. How do I comment code easily without resorting to plugins/scripts?

Comment: How doesn't it work for You? It works for me. Do You use // ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the [NERD commenter](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1218) plugin for vim, which has support for a whole bunch of languages (I'm sure C++ is one of them). With this installed, to comment/uncomment any line, use `<Leader>ci`. To do the same for a block of text, select text by entering the `visual` mode and use the same command as above.

There are other features in this such as comment `n` lines by supplying a count before the command, yank before comment with `<Leader>cy`, comment to end of line with `<Leader>c$`, and many others, which you can read about in the link. I've found this plugin to be extremely useful and is one of my 'must have' plugins.

Comment: I'm completely in love with "sexy" comments. Although it's a bit annoying for my coworkers when they want to undo them ... =)

Answer (score 30):

Use `ctrl-V` to do a block selection and then hit `I` followed by `//[ESC]`.

Alternatively, use `shift-V` to do a line-based select and then type `:s:^://[Enter]`. The latter part could easily go into a mapping. eg:

```
:vmap // :s:^://<CR>
```

Then you just `shift-V`, select the range, and type `//` (or whatever you bind it to).

Comment: ctrl-v or ctrl-V pastes yanked or deleted text. I am using VIM 7.3.

Comment: @Samaursa Are you talking about insert mode or normal mode? In normal mode ctrl-V enters block select, while in insert mode (and other modes where you enter text, like : and /) it enables "verbatim" for the next keypress. It sounds like you may have some sort mapping that's altering this behavior. Try using `:map`, `:nmap' or `:imap` to see what's going on.

Comment: might be using the mswin.vim script. It maps the ^V and ^C to the windows standard cut and paste. Try ^Q - (See gui_w32.txt - CTRL-V-alternative in the vim help).

Comment: @Laurence: Thanks, that was useful:Use ctrl-V to do a block selection and then hit I followed by //[ESC].

Answer (score 20):

You can add this to your `.vimrc` file

```
map <C-c> :s/^/\/\//<Enter>
```

Then when you need to comment a section just select all lines (Shift-V + movement) and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>.

To un-comment you can define in a similar way

```
map <C-u> :s/^\/\///<Enter>
```

that removes a `//` at begin of line from the selected range when pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>U</kbd>.

Comment: I was asking myself today how to do that.

Answer (score 3):

There's always `#ifdef CHECK_THIS_LATER` ... `#endif` which has the advantage of not causing problems with nested C-style comments (if you use them) and is easy to find and either uncomment or remove completely later.