# Indent and Comment multi-line code using mouse selection in Vim

Tags: vim

I am new to Vim and I temporarily can't get away from my mouse.

One feature that I am missing from IDEs is that I can select multiple lines with my mouse and press one key to Indent(Tab key) or Comment(<`C-M>`) them.

The Vim's way as I know (`<C-V>` ;many j-key strokes;`<Shift-I>`,//,`<ESC>` ) seems too many key strokes for me.

Is there a vim script that enables me to Indent and Comment my code block in the IDE's way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enabling mouse support saves several keypresses.

`:set mouse=a`

Now when you drag your mouse over a selection, it'll drop you into 'Visual Mode'.

1. From there you can simply use `>` and `<` for in/un-denting (or 2>, 3>)
2. For commenting, you'll need to remember change from Visual Mode into 'Visual Block Mode' first (so press `<C-V>` as before). Then, `I` , `//` , `<ESC>` as before.

I reckon that saves plenty of keystrokes. Hope you agree.

Comment: I'm using GVim on Windows, which has mswin.vim included. It drops me into "Selection Mode" rather than "Visual Mode" when I drag my mouse, and replace all my selection into a ">" when I press the `>` key.

Comment: bummer. I just installed gvim on Linux and it worked as expected. Hmmm, must be some wierd default option. Does it work if you do `<C-V>` before the `>` ?

Comment: mswin.vim replace <C-V> with <C-Q>,it works. But I have not quite escaped from the evil mouse.

Comment: @TomCaps: To get Vim to use Visual Mode for mouse try issuing command `:behave xterm`.  You could put this in your vimrc if it works for you.  I believe mswin.vim handles remapping of ctrl-v, ctrl-c, ctrl-x and mouse stuff is set by `:behave`.

Answer (score 2):

In C++ code, for instance:

```
>i{
```

Will indent a `{}` block.

See:

- [`:help >`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#%3E)
- [`:help i{`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#i%7B)

Commenting is a bigger beast. It is probably best that you employ a plug-in for this, such as [The NERD Commenter](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1218).

Answer (score 2):

Also, there are some ideas for comments here: [Easily comment (C++) code in vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5437708/easily-comment-c-code-in-vim)

And, using { and } to highlight blocks is a good replacement for "many j-key strokes"

Answer (score 1):

If you learn the habit of using whitespace lines at the appropriate times, most often

```
V}
```

will select exactly the block you wanted.

```
<C-v>}
```

does the same, but in virtual block selections. **Note** on windows, <kbd>C-v</kbd> may have gotten remapped to  <kbd>C-q</kbd>

### Indenting

```
>}         # indent until next whitespace line
>2}        # idem, but two blocks at once
V}o{       # expand visual selection both ways

.          # repeat last action

# so:
V}2j>      # indent following lines + two lines after next break
.          # twice
```

### Commenting

If you do **not** have any plugins,

```
<C-v>}I//<Esc>       # comment
<C-v>}x.             # uncomment
```

If you have NerdCommenter, it would be

```
V}<Leader>cc         # to comment
V}<Leader>cs         # to comment in to /* sexy */ blocks
V}<Leader>cu         # to uncomment
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have lines that have been highlighted by mouse just press `>` to indent them.  To unindent them press `<`.  These are keystrokes that relate to indenting and unindenting even without the mouse.

`>>`  --- Indent current line

`2>>` --- Indent current line + line underneath it

`3>>` --- Indent current line + 2 subsequent lines

etc.

You can select lines easily without the mouse by pressing `V` (that's a capital v) and then using any of Vim's many "motion" commands (or just the arrow keys) to extend the selection.  At any point you can then press `>` to indent the selection or `<` to unindent.