# How to comment C++ code in Vim with Ctrl - /?

Tags: c++, vim, nerdcommenter

So, I'm trying to set up the `NERDComment` plugin in vim, but I'm having some trouble with the keys.
And I want that if I use `Ctrl-/`, it must be done.
Can anybody answer this question?

Comment: I think this question belongs on https://vi.stackexchange.com/ and it already has an answer there [how to toggle comments with ctrl](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/8128/how-to-toggle-comments-with-ctrl)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5437708/easily-comment-c-code-in-vim you can find your answer here.