# How to toggle between comment and uncomment in Vim for Python code

Tags: python, vim, edit, comments

I wish to have a single command to **toggle** commenting in a line / block of python code.

I am using the following code in my `.vimrc` file:

```
" (un-)commenting
" comment line, selection with Ctrl-N,Ctrl-N
au BufEnter *.py nnoremap ,c mn:s/^\(\s*\)#*\(.*\)/\1#\2/ge<CR>:noh<CR>`n
au BufEnter *.py inoremap ,c <C-O>mn<C-O>:s/^\(\s*\)#*\(.*\)/\1#\2/ge<CR><C-O>:noh<CR><C-O>`n
au BufEnter *.py vnoremap ,c mn:s/^\(\s*\)#*\(.*\)/\1#\2/ge<CR>:noh<CR>gv`n
"
" " uncomment line, selection with Ctrl-N,N
au BufEnter *.py nnoremap ,u mn:s/^\(\s*\)#\([^ ]\)/\1\2/ge<CR>:s/^#$//ge<CR>:noh<CR>`n
au BufEnter *.py inoremap ,u <C-O>mn<C-O>:s/^\(\s*\)#\([^ ]\)/\1\2/ge<CR><C-O>:s/^#$//ge<CR><C-O>:noh<CR><C-O>`n
au BufEnter *.py vnoremap ,u mn:s/^\(\s*\)#\([^ ]\)/\1\2/ge<CR>gv:s/#\n/\r/ge<CR>:noh<CR>gv`n
```

(adapted from [this StackOverflow entry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2567010/234547))

but, is thee a way to have a toggle, that is, using the same shortcut to comment if it's uncommented or uncomment if it's commented?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's a quick way to comment/uncomment lines in Vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676632/whats-a-quick-way-to-comment-uncomment-lines-in-vim)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [vim-commentary](https://github.com/tpope/vim-commentary) plugin from Tim Pope. Then you can create a mapping, for example

```
nmap ,cc <Plug>CommentaryLine
```

With this mapping you can comment and uncomment with the same key sequence. It also automatically adapts to the file type. For not supported file types you can set `commentstring` manually.

The default mapping is `gcc` and it does exactly what you're looking for: toggle commented/uncommented.

Comment: An excellent plugin. The default mapping is `gcc` and it does exactly what you're looking for: toggle commented/uncommented.

Answer (score 5):

There's also [NERD Commenter](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdcommenter) from [Scrooloose](https://github.com/scrooloose), the maker of [NERD Tree](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree). It seems to [more extensive](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdcommenter/blob/master/plugin/NERD_commenter.vim) than [vim-commentary](https://github.com/tpope/vim-commentary/).

The only map I use though is `<leader>c<space>` (`,c` for my config), toggling a comment.