# How to use NERDComment plugin for Vim

Tags: vim, comments, nerdcommenter

I am new to Vim itself but I am trying to adopt this editor for my needs. I installed NERDComment plugin as described and have it listed in my `:scriptnames`.
But I don't understand from [description](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1218) and [this page](http://segfault.in/2010/01/vim-plugins-nerd-commenter/) how to use it. 
 I have filetype plugin on in *VIM/_vimrc* and when I do `,cc` (as I understand default  is `,`) it happens to work as `cc`* - Delete [count] lines [into register x] and start insert |linewise|.*

Please give me basic 'step-by-step' guide on `[count]<leader>cc |NERDComComment|` for example. I am pretty sure I just don't understand some kind of Vim concept so sorry if this question is lame.

Comment: do you have `filetype plugin on` in your vimrc? if you tried `<leader>cc` what was happened? please tell what's your problem?!

Comment: @Kent Yes, I have `filetype plugin on` in *VIM/_vimrc* and when I do `,cc` (as I understand default `<leader>` is `,`?) it happens to work as "["x]cc   Delete [count] lines [into register x] and start
   insert |linewise|."

Comment: @arbulgazar default `<leader>` is `\ ` (backslash)

Comment: Thank you @FDinoff that worked as it should! Why is that not listed in manual? Or am I getting this wrong?

Comment: @arbulgazar are you sure it is not listed in manual? it is a kind of `RTFM` thing. `:h mapleader` you can see `If "mapleader" is not set or empty, a backslash is used instead.`

Comment: @Kent I apologized for stupid questions in the topic post. I am first-day vim user and by far got only as far as `vimtutorial`. I will sure fulfill my knowledge in time. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Step by step**

- `[count]`  => number of lines to be commented, can be ommited
- `<leader>` => leader key, <kbd>\</kbd> by default. Many people change it to <kbd>,</kbd>.
- `cc`       => just <kbd>c</kbd><kbd>c</kbd>

**Visual mode**

Instead of count you can go into visual mode with <kbd>v</kbd> or <kbd>V</kbd>, select the lines you want to comment and then use <kbd>\</kbd><kbd>c</kbd><kbd>c</kbd>

**About leader key**

To know which one is your leader key you can use `:echo mapleader`, if that gives you `Undefined variable` the mapleader will be the default ('\').

You can check `:help leader` in vim for more info.

Answer (score 0):

when you are in visual mode: select the lines to be commented and type `,cc`.

when you are in normal mode: type `5,cc` for eg if you want to comment the next 5 lines.

*Note:* I have assumed the leader key to be a `comma(,)` - check yours using `:echo leader`

Comment: Not working for me, behaves like "["x]cc   Delete [count] lines [into register x] and start
   insert |linewise|." :(

Comment: check your leader key with `:echo leader` and substitute it for the `comma(,)`.