# About vim use, when insert comment character(eg. #)

Tags: python, vim

system: ubuntu 14.04.2

I use vim7.4 to write python code, sometimes I want to insert a '#' (comment), then vim takes this '#' to top of line.
Maybe I don't explain clearly.
example:
code:

```
if 'test' == 'abc':
    print 'something'
```

I want to insert a '#' in second line.Then this happens:

```
if 'test' == 'abc':
#   print 'something'
```

this happens automatically.

but what I want to do just like this:

```
if 'test' == 'abc':
    # print 'something'
```

Comment: My VIM does this fine in insert mode.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2561418/how-to-comment-out-a-block-of-python-code-in-vim

You must search before post ..

Comment: @B3mB4m There is no such rule. Also, that post is not a duplicate.

Comment: Normally if you have this kind of question, it would be helpful if you experiment with your `.vimrc` by removing lines until you get the exactly line or set of lines that causes this behavior. Then, if you post the minimal `.vimrc`, it will lead to more direct help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an issue with indenting of hash character `#`: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Restoring_indent_after_typing_hash

> Q: Why does Vim place # at the first column?
>
> A: You are using 'smartindent', or you have 0# in your 'cinkeys' or
>   'indentkeys' options.
>
> Under some circumstances, when you type a '#' character while in
>   insert mode, the indent on the current line will be removed. Also,
>   formatting or otherwise attempting to adjust the indent of a line
>   starting with '#' may not work as you expect.
>
> This tip discusses the issues and how problems can be avoided.

Comment: Thx. This happens, just because my .vimrc file has 'set cindent'. So if I take a comment, it will not happen.