# Vim response quite slow

Tags: vim, editor

If I open a file containing 5,000 lines of code and continue to input, I found that my vim became very slow, it displays my input after about 1s.

It even won't become any better after I start up with `--noplugin`. But after switching my  `.vimrc` file, everything gets fine again. The `.vimrc` file is written by myself and after checking for some time, I still can't locate the error. I have clear all the key maps, but the problem still exists.

So can you give my any advise or tell my how to debug in vim? I found there is a debug option but can't get how to work.

Comment: Janus used by any chance? If so that seems to be a common problem. If xou don't depend on fugitive, disable it. https://github.com/carlhuda/janus/issues/396

Comment: Thanks three. I don't know the version of vim now. But it seems that it's not caused by vim, but the script written by me have some problem.

Comment: What is the file type? Is that XML? Did you try `:syn off` ?

Comment: It's java file. Sorry, but it's in the computer of company. I will post it when i return to company.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the `--startuptime` option when start vim:

```
--startuptime {fname}                   *--startuptime*
        During startup write timing messages to the file {fname}.
        This can be used to find out where time is spent while loading
        your .vimrc, plugins and opening the first file.
        When {fname} already exists new messages are appended.
        (Only available when compiled with the |+startuptime|
        feature).
```

Take following steps to diagnose the problem:

- type **`vim --startuptime log.txt main.java`** in bash to start vim
- type **`:tabe log.txt`** in vim to view the log.

Comment: Hi kav. My vim isn't slow on startup.

Answer (score 11):

The reason for slowness is often the not set or wrong set ruby_path on compile time of vim ([see also discussion on google vim/ruby google group](https://github.com/vim-ruby/vim-ruby/issues/33)). It is easier to set it in vimrc, because you can change it without recompiling vim. You can set the path through the **g:ruby_path** variable in your .vimrc file. Don't copy and paste both, use the right one.

If you setup RBENV you have to use this one:

```
" ruby path if you are using rbenv
let g:ruby_path = system('echo $HOME/.rbenv/shims')
```

If you setup RVM you have to use this one:

```
" ruby path if you are using RVM
let g:ruby_path = system('rvm current')
```

You can also use the [vim-rbenv](https://github.com/tpope/vim-rbenv) plugin, which sets the path too.

For me the part on loading ruby specific functions in vim got 10 times faster.

If you are using jruby, than the start up slowliness can be even bigger. See examples for fixing it [here](https://github.com/vim-ruby/vim-ruby/issues/33).

Comment: Indeed, forcing a ruby path through this method improves vim's startup speed substantially. Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

If running vim 7.4,

put this in your .vimrc

set regexpengine=1

vim 7.4 has a new regex engine that appear not to work well in some situations. Previous version vim 7.3 used the old engine ( set regexpengine=1 ).

The "slow response" from syntax highlighting problem affects the vim help files as well ( and .vimrc file too ).

Comment: `:set regexpengine=1` -- This is a great find that *no other expert* mentioned. I got some improvement (but not full) after this change. 

One other reason for my slow down was `:set relativenumber` which is causing a lot of screen redraws effectively showing a slowdown.

Answer (score 7):

Something like this is usually caused by syntax colouring. Try with `:syntax off`.

Comment: It shouldn't present any problem on files that size (~5000lines), mine are significantly bigger and still no slowdown. If it was 500000 lines, maybe ...

Comment: It's not syntax problem.I have changed to other's vimrc and the syntax is on. It works fine.thanks.

Comment: When i turned syntax off, the problem solved. But it will also speed up when i change vimrc file. I have refer to the same syntax in these two vimrc files.

Comment: This was the answer for me with syntax coloring YAML files.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add these lines to your `~/.vimrc` or `~/.config/nvim/init.vim`:

```
set lazyredraw   " don't redraw everytime
set synmaxcol=128  " avoid slow rendering for long lines
syntax sync minlines=64  " faster syntax hl
```

Also if you're using tmux, consider adding this to your `~/.tmux.conf`:

```
set -sg escape-time 10
```