# My Vim has gone slower by the time

Tags: vim

Vim was much faster on the time when I installed it freshly. It now takes 2-4 seconds from the time I hit enter after typing `vim` inside terminal and the opening of Vim (even without any file/argument).

I have:

- 7 plugins (autocorrect, auto-pairs, closetag, snipMate, supertab, tetris)
- **No** colorschemes
- A `.vimrc` file with [these configurations](https://gist.github.com/3155795)
- The `.vimrc` file in my home directory is a symlink, the real file is in `.vim` directory
- I am starting Vim in insert mode (I have alias in `.bash_aliases` file):

  ```
  alias vim="vim -c 'startinsert'"
  alias vi="vi -c 'startinsert'"
  ```

What is slowing down my Vim?

Comment: One thing to try is to run `vim -X` and see if it starts up quicker.  I had slowness issues that were related to vim trying to connect to a non-existent X server.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I'm almost sure that `autocorrect.vim` is the reason. Just looked into it and saw 8152 lines. All these lines are parsed by Vim at its startup, which slows it down.

For the future. You can start vim with `--startuptime` argument to know exactly what slows down its loading, e.g.

```
vim --startuptime startup.report
```

Examining of produced file will give you information about time spent for loading different scripts.

Comment: Nice, so is it `autocorrect.vim` who slowed down startup of your Vim or there is/was another reason for that?

Answer (score 2):

Check the size of your viminfo file.

ls -l ~/.viminfo

My VIM becomes really slow when this file grows to very large (200MB) and everytime VIM quits, it needs to write to this file and it's pretty slow. The reason that this file gets really large for me is 1: I used VIM for long, and 2: I yank/copy very large text in VIM and all those text appear in .viminfo.

Do

rm ~/.viminf*

make sure to remove ~/.viminfz.*. Otherwise, .viminfo will be restored even if you delete .viminfo.

After they are removed, my VIM is as fast as it should be.

You can also log via

vim -V12log test.txt

to see what is being done (I found that vim is trying to write to .viminfo in the log).

There are also starttime record feature provided by vim
refer to this [Vim response quite slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9341768/vim-response-quite-slow)