# Insert character without entering insert mode?

Tags: vim, shortcut, keymapping

Sometimes I want to insert a  `#` to comment out a line and test it quickly. Currently I do:

<kbd>i</kbd><kbd>#</kbd><kbd>ESC</kbd><kbd>:</kbd><kbd>w</kbd>

Is there something shorter I can do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's a quick way to comment/uncomment lines in Vim?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676632/whats-a-quick-way-to-comment-uncomment-lines-in-vim)

Comment: There are many comment scripts. I use commentary.vim: https://github.com/tpope/vim-commentary

Comment: As others have said, you might want to try a plugin for comments. More generally, though, if you have a simple action that you need to do often or repetitively, you can easily create a mapping or macro.

Comment: using neovim 0.5 in 2021, i make little todo items in readme files and i often have `- [ ] ` in markdown, and i'd like to add a `x` to signify i've completed my item. so i use,

`r` to go into replace char mode and then type `x` to fill in the empty char (if you will) 

seems to work quite well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Although I agree with others that there are [better ways to comment and uncomment code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1676690/1284644), it seems that people have gotten distracted and forgotten to actually answer the question.

This is my approach to inserting a single character:

```
:noremap <key> i <Esc>r
```

I tend to find that I need to replace, remove, or add single characters very often if I'm correcting typos, so (resp.) `r`, `x`, and whatever is chosen for `<key>` in the above become very handy.

Note that `.` is also particularly handy for this sort of task. It repeats the previous action.

Personally though, I only map this function to a valuable key when I'm doing a task where I use it frequently enough to justify occupying a prime spot on the keyboard (such as correcting typos), because really, it only saves one keystroke per use and that's only when `<key>` is not a combination, which of course limits availability.

Comment: maybe it only saves one key stroke, but it also saves the mental overhead of switching modes, which should feel significant in vim.

Comment: This mapping [doesn't work](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/5176/is-there-a-way-to-insert-a-single-character-and-then-exit-insert-mode#comment9880_5177) with `.`

Answer (score 3):

I map a couple of things to my `<leader>` key (`\` by default):

```
" # comment the current line
nnoremap <leader>d I#<ESC>

" block comment in visual mode
vnoremap <leader>c <ESC>'<O/*<ESC>'>o*/<ESC>V'<k
```

If you want to add a `#` to the start of a group of lines, then do this:

1. `<ctl-v>`
2. `j` (as many times as necessary
3. `I#`
4. `<esc>`

Answer (score 2):

You could use a recording. From normal mode, type:

```
qlml0i#<press escape>`lq
```

Then to comment out a line, just press `@l`

Answer (score 2):

Mapping in vim is so easy that I might do something like

```
:nmap CC I#<Esc>:w<CR>
```

on the fly.  If I get used to it, then I will add it to my vimrc file.

```
:help key-mapping
:help usr_40.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is a plugin you might wanna take a look at:

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1218

It is specifically designed for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I'm particularly fond of the [tComment](https://github.com/vim-scripts/tComment) plugin. gcc to comment a line, repeat to uncomment, multiple lines, motions, etc.