# vim comment/uncomment with one mapping

Tags: function, vim, mapping, comments

I'm new(bie) in vim. I've got the following mapping to comment my python code :

```
nmap cc 0i#<ESC>
```

I would like to have the same mapping to uncomment a line. I think I need an function to check the first character of the line. Do you know how I could do the tricks ?

thanks.

edit : It's not the same as that [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676632) , I wonder how to do that without plugin.

Comment: Please [find a good comment plugin](http://vimawesome.com/?q=comment). Also be aware that `cc` is already used by Vim to change an entire line (Same as `S`). See `:h cc`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't attempt to implement this (poorly) yourself; this is a solved problem, and you can choose from several good plugins. See [Comment Lines according to a given filetype](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Comment_Lines_according_to_a_given_filetype#Related_plugins) for a list of plugins.

---

As a learning experience, attempting a mapping is fine, though. Here's one approach that uses `:help map-expr` to check the line for the existence of a comment first:

```
nnoremap <expr> cc getline('.') =~# '^#' ? '0x' : '0i#<ESC>'
```

PS: [You should use `:noremap`](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/05.html); it makes the mapping immune to remapping and recursion.

Answer (score 1):

There is this [plugin](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdcommenter). It's very good and he works for many languages.