# vim 7.4 comment/uncomment lines in Vim without plugins

Tags: vim

I tried out answers in [What's a quick way to comment/uncomment lines in Vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676632/whats-a-quick-way-to-comment-uncomment-lines-in-vim), but they don't work. Pressing `shift i` on visual mode after selection just brings me in insert mode. I run it with `--noplugin`, no use.

Comment: The question you refer answers your question, it should work. Before doing `shift i` you need to do `Ctrl V` to go to the visual block selection mode, you should see that when you move the cursor, you select the block (rectangle area) and not the whole lines. Then `shift i` should jump to the start of the block and enter the insert mode. Once you finish typing the text and press `Esc`, the text you typed should appear in every line of the block you had selected.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's a quick way to comment/uncomment lines in Vim?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676632/whats-a-quick-way-to-comment-uncomment-lines-in-vim)

Comment: @BorisSerebrov yeah you write i was inattentive and was doing `shift V`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are *many* ways to comment/uncomment in Vim. Anyway, assuming "C++-style" comments, eg. `// foobar`…

**Commenting a single line**

```
I// <Esc>
```

**Uncommenting a single line**

```
^dw
```

**Commenting several lines**

```
vjjj
:'<,'>norm! I// <CR>
```

or

```
<C-v>jjj
I// <Esc>
```

**Uncommenting several lines**

```
vjjj
:'<,'>norm! ^dw<CR>
```

or

```
<C-v>jjjllld
```

Answer (score 2):

You might need to take visual block before proceeding , <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd> to use it. More at `help blockwise-visual`

Then, use any nagivation keys like `h,j,k,l`, followed by `I`, then insert your comment character like `#` or `//` and finalize by  <kbd>Esc</kbd>.

This should comment whole block.

To uncomment, repeat the same operation of visual block and navigation but replace `I` by any delete operation like `x` for `#` or `2x` for `//`.
Hope this helps