# How to add comments to multiple lines in VIM?

Tags: vim

I know how to **comment out** multiple lines in VIM, but what if I wanted to **add** comments in the end of each line?
For example:

```lua
function dir.ls(path)
    local i,files = 0,{}
    local pfile = io.popen('ls "'..path..'"')
    for fname in pfile:lines() do
        i = i + 1
        fpath = path..fname
        files[i] = fpath
    end
    pfile:close()
    return files
end
```

Now with added comments:

```lua
function dir.ls(path)
    local i,files = 0,{}
    local pfile = io.popen('ls "'..path..'"')
    for fname in pfile:lines() do
        i = i + 1
        fpath = path..fname  -- your comment goes here
        files[i] = fpath -- your comment goes here
    end
    pfile:close() -- your comment goes here
    return files
end
```

Comment: I found another question similar to yours, you may wanna check it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676632/whats-a-quick-way-to-comment-uncomment-lines-in-vim

Comment: This is **commenting out** the lines, I want to **add** comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Append your comment to the first line:

   ```
   A -- your comment goes here<Esc>
   ```
2. Move the cursor to the next line you want to add a comment to.
3. Repeat the last edit:

   ```
   .
   ```
4. And so on…

In your example:

```
A -- your comment goes here<Esc>
j.
jj.
```

Another method, but in a single step:

```
:,+3v/end/norm A -- your comment goes here<CR>
```

That command is easier to understand if it is explained from right to left:

- The `:normal` command allows you to execute a sequence of normal mode commands from command-line mode. Here, we use it to append the comment to the given line, just like in the first step of the multi-step method.
- `v/pattern/command` is a companion to the `:global` command. It means "run the given command on every line in the given range that *doesn't* match `pattern`". Here, we run our `:normal` command on every line in the given range that doesn't contain `end`.
- `,+3` is the range of lines on which we want to run the `:v` command. It is a shortened version of `.,+3` which means "the current line and the next three lines".

Comment: I see, can you please explain how the single step method works?