# How to remove row lines in vim?

Tags: vim

How do i remove the row lines at the start of the line? I typed the command

```
:s/^/# /
```

while in command mode and it suddenly appeared. I typed the command again, but it's still in my editor. I was trying to comment out a few blocks of code. This is the stackoverflow page I was following: [What's a quick way to comment/uncomment lines in Vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676632/whats-a-quick-way-to-comment-uncomment-lines-in-vim)

Please see the image below to see what I'm pertaining to. Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: Try `:noh` or `:nohlsearch`.  I suspect the issue is that you've matched the beginning of every line and vim is highlighting this match by showing an underscore.

Comment: Cool this makes sense. Thanks! @RandyMorris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vim highlights the current search pattern; this is the `'incsearch'` option; either you have it explicitly turned on in your `~/.vimrc`, or you use a recent Vim 8 version that has this enabled by the defaults.

Check with `:hi IncSearch`; it should show the same *white-underscore-onblack* formatting as your screenshot. You can also use a `:hi` command to customize this (or choose a different colorscheme).

To turn this off, use

```
:nohlsearch
```

You can shorten that to `:noh`; some people also define a mapping to quickly clear this. Alternatively, you can also search for something else.