# Vim command to comment out a selection of lines?

Tags: vim

Say I have a bunch of lines:

```
@Override
public void draw(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);
    g.fillRect(rectangle.x, rectangle.y, rectangle.width, rectangle.height);
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.drawRect(rectangle.x, rectangle.y, rectangle.width, rectangle.height);
}
```

When I want to comment them out with `//` (i prefer line comments instead of block comments), what I do is:

- Place the cursor infront of the `@` symbol
- `Ctrl-V`: Switch to enter block-select mode
- Select the column down to the `}` closing parenthesis using multiple hits of `j`
- `Shift-I`: to enter block-insert
- Type `//`
- `ESC` to excit
- `Enter` to finish the command

--> The lines are now commented out.

Is there an easier way where I don't need to do the block-select? I found I can use a substitution like `:'<, '>s/^/\/\///g` but this has two problems:

1. Its very clumsy and error prone to type (multiple forward and backward slashes need to be
   escaped)
2. It places the comment symbols (`//`) at the beginning of
   the line (position 0), not at the position where the first character
   of that line was (so indentation is lost).

How can I insert `//` on the selected lines at the position of the first character of each line using Vi?

Comment: I concur that you would be happier with a plugin, but I just want to let you know that `:s` is flexible with delimiters so you can pick e.g. `#` instead of `/`; also, since you are only replacing once per line (at the start of the line), `g` is not doing anything useful; so this much simpler statement works, and no need to escape anything: `:'<,'>s#^#//`

Answer (score 3):

You can define a custom mapping or command for your `:substitute`.

However, there are several commenter plugins that do this very well, and those are generic (and often extensible) so that they work for any filetype:

- [NERD Commenter plugin](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1218)
- [tComment plugin](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1173)
- [commentary.vim plugin](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3695)

I'd highly recommend to use one of those plugins instead of trying to reinvent a poor solution yourself.

Comment: I like Commentary: it's super simple, and does everything I need. Select, `gc` — commented. Select, `gc` — uncommented. (You can also `gcu` to uncomment the comment block you're in, without selecting).

Comment: @Amadan gc works with text objects too, so `gcap` is easier than e.g., `vapgc`. It’s also a text object, so `dgc` does what you’d expect!

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Yeah, I know. I just meant, the only sequence to remember is `gc` (and `gcu`); everything else is derived from `gc` in a standard way: `gcgc` (like `dd`), `gcG` (like dG), `v...gc` (like `v...d`)... It's just that `ap` is not typically what I use with code, as I will often have line breaks within a function. `va{okgc` for a general case would be preferable unless I am sure I can shorten it.

Comment: Thanks for the references. Can this also be enabled for the Vim-Plugin of Intellij IDEA?

Comment: Vim plugins typically just support simple mappings, but not the whole Vimscript, so no. But you can probably leverage IDEA's built-in keys (i.e. `Ctrl-/`) for commenting lines.

Answer (score 1):

I use Commentary as in the other answer, but a few thoughts:

- `<C-v>jjjjj` could be `<C-v>}` or `<C-v>/}<CR>`
- `:substitute` doesn’t have to use `/` as a separator: `:'<,'>s-^-//`
- with a visual selection, you can also do `:'<,'>normal! I//`

Answer (score 1):

> How can I insert // on the selected lines at the position of the first character of each line using Vi?

Although, I'm agree with others and the dedicated plugin is a must have, but, as it is formulated in the OP, that's quite an easy task which can be implemented as one-liner:

```
vnoremap <silent>gc :call setline(".", printf("%*s" . &cms, indent("."), "", trim(getline("."))))<CR>
```

Now select some text, press "gc", and, voila, it works. To force `//` usage instead of the default `/**/` set the following option for your buffer: `setlocal cms=//\ %s`. See `:h 'cms'`.

Answer (score 0):

" I have a 'toggle comment function' that looks like
" Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24652257/2571881

```
" these lines are needed for ToggleComment()
" Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24652257/2571881
autocmd FileType c,cpp,java      let b:comment_leader = '//'
autocmd FileType arduino         let b:comment_leader = '//'
autocmd FileType sh,ruby,python  let b:comment_leader = '#'
autocmd FileType zsh             let b:comment_leader = '#'
autocmd FileType conf,fstab      let b:comment_leader = '#'
autocmd FileType matlab,tex      let b:comment_leader = '%'
autocmd FileType vim             let b:comment_leader = '"'

function! ToggleComment()
    if exists('b:comment_leader')
        let l:pos = col('.')
        let l:space = ( &ft =~ '\v(c|cpp|java|arduino)' ? '3' : '2' )
        if getline('.') =~ '\v(\s*|\t*)' .b:comment_leader
            let l:space -= ( getline('.') =~ '\v.*\zs' . b:comment_leader . '(\s+|\t+)@!' ?  1 : 0 )
            execute 'silent s,\v^(\s*|\t*)\zs' .b:comment_leader.'[ ]?,,g'
            let l:pos -= l:space
        else
            exec 'normal! 0i' .b:comment_leader .' '
            let l:pos += l:space
        endif
        call cursor(line("."), l:pos)
    else
        echo 'no comment leader found for filetype'
    end
endfunction
nnoremap <Leader>t :call ToggleComment()<CR>
inoremap <Leader>t <C-o>:call ToggleComment()<CR>
xnoremap <Leader>t :'<,'>call ToggleComment()<CR>
" vnoremap <Leader>t :call ToggleComment()<CR>
```

So, once you have this function on your `~/.vimrc` you can do:

```
vip ...................... visual inner paragraph
<leader>t ................ in order to call the function
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a macro with `q`, lets put it into the `a` buffer, so hit `qa` on a given line. Then press `I//` to jump to start of line, and comment it out. hit <kbd>Esc</kbd> and `q` and now your macro is done. This macro will comment out the current line.
The full command is `qaI//`<kbd>Esc</kbd>`q`

Now visually select a bunch of lines with `V`, and type `:norm!@a` to run your `a` macro over those lines. This will comment out a bunch of lines.

Record another macro to do the opposite with `qb^xx`. This can be invoked by visually selecting the lines you want to uncomment and typing `norm!@b`

You can save these macros in your .vimrc and map the specific macro to a key combination if you want to "save" these commands.