# vim: Uncomment/comment current line without moving cursor

Tags: vim

I am editing a file in vim and currently my cursor is in the middle of this line:

```
# foo bar baz foo bar baz foo bar baz foo bar baz
```

Using JetBrains/PyCharm/VSCode, I can hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> to uncomment/comment the line without moving the cursor left or right.  Is this possible in vim?

This does not solve my problem: [What's a quick way to comment/uncomment lines in Vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676632/whats-a-quick-way-to-comment-uncomment-lines-in-vim)

Comment: This similar discussion may be useful to you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676632/whats-a-quick-way-to-comment-uncomment-lines-in-vim

Answer (score 2):

You may want to use some plugin, for example: commentary by tim pope is a lightweight plugin with basic functionality: https://vimawesome.com/plugin/commentary-vim

"Comment stuff out." is the first line in the Readme.
With commentary-vim installed and running, navigate to the line you want to comment out (your cursor can be in the middle of the line), then hit `gcl` to comment out that line and stay with the cursor at the exact position. In python a `#`  (hash and space) will be inserted, so the text will be shifted 2 positions to the right, but the cursor will stay exactly at the position as it was before. Use `gcl` again to uncomment the line.

If you want your plugin to do more fancy stuff, take a look at the Nerd Commenter: https://vimawesome.com/plugin/the-nerd-commenter

Another lightweight plugin you may want to take a look at: https://github.com/tomtom/tcomment_vim

If you want to avoid installing plugins I'd suggest you write your custom key binding / shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

Warning: this is not elegant. It assumes that the comment you want to remove always looks like the one in your question. But it works.

This would work as a macro or a keybinding, as far as I can tell.

```
mc02x`c2h
```

1. `mc` sets a mark named "c" at the current location
2. `0` moves to the beginning of the line
3. `2x` deletes the first two characters it finds there
4. `` `c `` returns to the mark you created in step one
5. `2h` moves you left two characters

Comment: this link has great information on formatting text on this site:
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks#:~:text=To%20use%20literal%20backticks%20at,yields%20the%20Perl%20%24%60%20operator.

Comment: Although the title of my question says "uncomment", the actual functionality, implemented in many other editors, is comment/uncomment with the same key. I will update the title of my question to emphasize this. Thank you!

Comment: @Udi That's beyond my skill level, then. Sorry. Closest I could come to that is adding key bindings to integrate [Thomas Jensen's boxes utility](https://boxes.thomasjensen.com/editors-vim.html) into vim. I love that tool but I don't use it often enough to feel good about putting it in my config.