# Vim: Customise Shortcut keys for commenting code blocks in MacOS

Tags: vim

I am a newbie of Vim and I am using MacOS. In MacOS we usually use `cmd`  and `\` to comment the code block and  I also want to achieve this in my Vim setting. Following to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1676672/16039322), I know how to modify the `~/.vimrc` to comment different languages like C++ and Python. The remaining part is setting a shortcut key for commenting which I have no clue on that. Is it possible to set `cmd`  and `\` as a shortcut key for commenting in Vim?  Or is it possible to use non-alphabetic symbols to form shortcut keys?

Comment: What did you find so far when you searched for "vim create shortcut"?

Comment: @mkrieger1. Thanks for your reply.   I do some search on "vim create shortcut". I think what I need to change is the ```noremap``` function to ``` <D-/>. From ```:help <D-``` in vim it tells me that ```<D-``` can be used as command key. So I am wondering why ```<D-/>``` does not work.

Comment: `<D-` only works  in the MacVim GUI.

Answer (score 0):

First…

> In MacOS we usually use `cmd` and `\` to comment the code block

No, this has very little to do with macOS. Beyond the basics like "open file", "copy", etc. what sequence or combination of keys does what is decided at the application level. The only OS-specific part, here, is the use of the `command` key but macOS editors/IDEs can use whatever they want (IntelliJ uses `cmd+/`, for example).

Second…

When Vim is executed in a terminal emulator on macOS, it is incapable of seeing the `cmd` key or any combination that includes the `cmd` key so you can forget about mapping anything to `cmd`+`\` in that context.

When using the [MacVim](https://github.com/macvim-dev/macvim) GUI, the `cmd` key can be used in mappings as `<D-`: `cmd`+`\` would be `<D-\>`. While that would work in the MacVim GUI, I would advise against doing it because it is not portable.